# Scale Div to Smartphone Width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a before/after slider working correctly on my website.  I'm almost there, but the DIV is not properly scaling on mobile browsers.  It extends way past the width of my smartphone screen.

[Here's a link to the website page I'm working on](http://www.peterzelinka.com/tutorials).

About halfway down you'll see a Polarizer section with the Before / After slider.  It looks fine on my Desktop browser, but on mobile it extends past the screen width.  My coding skills are pretty weak, so I may be missing something simple here.

[Here's where I got the Before / After code from.](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/beforeandafter.htm)

I assume I just need to insert a basic property into one of the CSS sections below?  I've already added the viewport code into the head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style type="text/css">div.beforeandafter{ /* main container */
background: white;
display: block;
height: 630x; /* default height of main container */
overflow: hidden;
position: relative; 
width: 944px; /* default width of main container */
```

}

```
div.before, div.after{ /* before and after DIVs within main container */
height: 100%;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out; /* CSS transition. Actual duration set inside script (options.revealduration) */
width: 100%;
z-index: 100;
```

}

```
div.after{
z-index: 1; /* z-index of after div should be smaller than before's */
```

}

```
div.drag{ /* main div used for separating and dragging between before and after slides */
background: white;
cursor: col-resize;
display: block;
height: 100%;
left: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out; /* transition. 0.4s sets duration of drag fade in time */
width: 2px; /* width of drag bar separator */
z-index: 1001;
```

}

```
div.drag div.draghandle{ /* handle bar within drag interface */
background: darkred;
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
background: rgb(169,3,41);
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(169,3,41,1)), color-stop(44%,rgba(143,2,34,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(109,0,25,1)));
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#6d0019',GradientType=1 );
height: 20%; /* height of drag handle */
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
width: 16px; /* width of drag handle */
```

}

```
div.before span.caption, div.after span.caption{ /* CSS to syle SPAN caption. Optional */
background: black;
bottom: 10px;
color: white;
display: block;
font: bold 12px Germand;
padding: 5px;
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
width: 90px;
```

}

```
div.before span.caption{
left: 10px;
right: auto;
```

}

```
div.before span.caption a, div.after span.caption a{
color: lightyellow;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

Finally, here's the actual DIV:

```
<div class="beforeandafter" id="baf" style="width:944px; height:630px; ">
```

Comment: try using `width` in `%` instead of `px` to make it responsively fit to device width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a defined height and width as inline styles in your HTML

```
<div class="beforeandafter" id="baf" style="width:944px; height:630px; ">
```

Change that to

```
<div class="beforeandafter" id="baf">
```

Then in your CSS document, remove `height: 630px;` and `width: 944px` from `div.beforeandafter` and add `padding-bottom: 66.73728814%`

Comment: That did it!  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Peter sweet, no problem :)